# Unclear behavior at specific error handling

Tags: go

I'm trying to handle specific errors but I'm surprised about the behavior.

**Examples:**

If I use

```
if err == errors.New("something"){}`
```

it returns `true`, even if `err` is `nil`.

If I use

```
if err.String() == "something"`
```

it panics when `err` is `nil`.

I really expected

```
err == errors.New("something")`
```

to work and I'm not sure why it returns `true`.

**Some more code:**

Here is some code to clarify the question ([Play](http://play.golang.org/p/IMVWeupQQ2)):

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "errors"

func main() {

    e := errors.New("error")
    //I'm expecting this to return true
    if e == errors.New("error") {
        fmt.Println("Hello, playground")
    }
}
```

Comment: compare specific error types, not *new* errors. Is there a particular error you're having trouble with?

Comment: @JimB  doesn't ``errors.New`` return an error value of type error ? How is that different than an error returned by a function or an error declared as variable given that the underlaying value is same ?

Comment: The underlying value *isn't* the same. The `error` interface returned by `errors.New` contains a pointer (to a private struct), and each invocation will give you an `error` containing a new value. That is why you always compare to a specific predeclared value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you can do:

- compare `err.Error()`: `if err != nil && err.Error() == "something"`
- use global variables for your errors

Here is an example for the second solution:

```
package my_package

var ErrSmth = errors.New("something")

func f() error {
    return ErrSmth
}
```

---

```
package main

import "my_package"

func main() {
    err := f()
    if err == my_package.ErrSmth {
         // Do something
    }
}
```

The second solution is the way specific errors are handled with the [`io`](http://golang.org/pkg/io/#pkg-variables) package.

Comment: To expand on @julienc 's answer:

Take a look at the [Comparison Operators](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Comparison_operators) in the spec.

An `error` type is an [interface type](http://golang.org/pkg/builtin/#error).

From the spec:
Interface values are comparable. Two interface values are equal if they have identical dynamic types and equal dynamic values or if both have value nil.

Comment: Tbh I still don't understand why a comparison between an error and errors.New doesn't returns true if both actually have the same "dynamic" value (I guess this is the error string) but I marked the answer as correct b/c the 1st solution makes sense.